# react-native useState error ("is read-only")

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

When running the code below in react-native, I get a "buttonColor is read-only" error.

I've been reviewing documentation from various places on useState but am still not sure what is causing this particular error.

I would expect for the button to alternate between 'green' (the initial state) and 'red' after each subsequent tap, but it just show green on the first render and then I get the error message after the first tap.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

const ColorSquare = () => {

    const[buttonColor, setColor] = useState('green');

    const changeColor = () => {

        if (buttonColor='green') {
            setColor('red')
        } else if (buttonColor='red') {
            setColor('green')
        } else {
            setColor('blue')
        }
    }

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{backgroundColor:buttonColor, padding: 15}}
                onPress={()=>changeColor()}
                  >
              <Text style={styles.text}>Change Color!</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
};  

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text:{
      color:'white'
      },
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
  });

export default ColorSquare;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are assigning the value of button color instead of comparing it i.e using `=` instead of  `===`. You are basically setting a value to button color which is wrong.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

const ColorSquare = () => {

    const[buttonColor, setColor] = useState('green');

    const changeColor = () => {

        if (buttonColor==='green') { // use === instead of == //
            setColor('red')
        } else if (buttonColor==='red') { // use === instead of == //
            setColor('green')
        } else {
            setColor('blue')
        }
    }

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{backgroundColor:buttonColor, padding: 15}}
                onPress={()=>changeColor()}
                  >
              <Text style={styles.text}>Change Color!</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
};  

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text:{
      color:'white'
      },
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
  });

export default ColorSquare;
```

Comment: Hopes this helps.!

Comment: will do as soon as it lets me (apparently there is a timer...)

Comment: @mtbell One more thing. Your onPress in TouchableOpacity is an arrow function. It's not a good practice as every time the button is press an arrow function is used and new function is created every single time. You should use `onPress={changeColor}` as this won't create a new function on every press on touchableOpacity.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer posted by Atin above, I also thought of a way to do this using numerical values and an array of colors which I ultimately chose to go with due to needing some underlying binary representation of the data.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

const ColorSquare = () => {

    const[buttonNumber, setNumber] = useState(0);

    const colors = ['green','red']

    const changeColor = () => {

        if (buttonNumber<1) {
            setNumber(buttonNumber => buttonNumber + 1)
        } else {
            setNumber(buttonNumber => buttonNumber - 1)
        }
    }

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{backgroundColor:colors[buttonNumber], padding: 15}}
                onPress={()=>changeColor()}
                  >
              <Text style={styles.text}>Change Color!</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
};  

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text:{
      color:'white'
      },
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
  });

export default ColorSquare;
```

Answer (score 0):

HI there if you are in 2021 having this problem I want to show you something that I was doing wrong

In my case I was trying to use a handleChange function to setState look here below

```
 const handleChange = (e) => {
    setCustomerLogin({...customerLogin, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
```

I was getting a setCustomerLogin is ready only and its because I wrapped the (e) in the above example.

Solution is

```
 const handleChange = e => {
     setCustomerLogin({...customerLogin, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
```